multicol 1st column misalignment
I am trying to use multicol to place data in a table form. For some reason my first column is uneven compared to the rest of the table. is there a way to fix this?

\item Here is text that goes before the multicol.\\
  \begin{multicols}{5}
    \begin{align*}
    X_1\\
    5\\
    6\\
    74\\
    4\\
    1 
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
    X_2\\
    9\\
    74\\
    2422\\
    299\\
    338  
 \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
    X_3\\
    162\\
    281\\
    2778\\
    36\\
    39
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
    X_4\\
    19\\
    2\\
    6\\
    26\\
    985
    \end{align*}
   \begin{align*}
    Total (\sum X_i)\\
    43\\
    73\\
    100\\
    11\\
    13 
    \end{align*}
  \end{multicols}



why are you using multioc at all or align when there are no alignments? Your output looks like a simple tabular?

Thank you! I will try tabular... Apologies, I am just getting back into using LaTeX after having not used it for more than a decade...

Welcome (back?) to TeX.SE!

In addition to arranging the data in a table, I'd (a) insert a line break in the header cell of the final column and (b) align the numbers on their (here implicit) decimal markers.

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type (align numbers on dec. markers)
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1.0]}

\begin{document} 

\[
\begin{array}{@{} T{2} T{4} T{4} T{3} T{3} @{}}
{X_1} & {X_2} & {X_3} & {X_4} & 
   {\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} Total \\ $\bigl(\sum X_i\bigr)$ \end{tabular}} \\
\midrule
    5   & 9    & 19   & 19  & 43  \\
    6   & 74   & 281  & 2   & 73  \\
    74  & 2422 & 2778 & 6   & 100 \\
    4   & 299  & 36   & 26  & 11  \\
    1   & 338  & 39   & 985 & 13 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


I'd rather use simple math environment:
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Here is text that goes before the data.
    \[
    \begin{array}{r r r r r}
        X_1 &  X_2 &  X_3 & X_4 & \textrm{Total} \left(\sum X_i\right) \\
        5   &    9 &  162 &  19 &  43 \\
        6   &   74 &  281 &   2 &  73 \\
        74  & 2422 & 2778 &   6 & 100 \\
        4   &  299 &   36 &  26 &  11 \\
        1   &  338 &   39 & 985 &  13 \\
        
    \end{array}
    \]
    \item The next text after the data.
\end{enumerate}

Which produces:

